PyTorch's _PositiveDefinite() check failed on entire batch of 2x2 covariance matrices, but succeeded on all individual matrices?
I was wondering if any with experience with PyTorch rounding error or the PositiveDefinite check on the 2x2 covariance matrix could help me understand this issue better?
Error was that…
Exception has occurred: ValueError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
Expected parameter covariance_matrix (Tensor of shape (117, 100, 20, 2, 2)) of distribution MultivariateNormal(loc: torch.Size([117, 100, 20, 2]), covariance_matrix: torch.Size([117, 100, 20, 2, 2])) to satisfy the constraint PositiveDefinite(), but found invalid values:…
Covariance matrix is constructed like this and is passed into MultivariateNormal class. Basically, from sigma_x, sigma_y and rho_xy, construct the covariance matrix in the standard steps from textbooks. By definition, a matrix constructed this way is positive-definite.
sigma_x_hat = Gaussian_mixture_params_reshaped[:, :, :, 3] 
        sigma_x = torch.exp(sigma_x_hat) * math.sqrt(temperature)
        sigma_y_hat = Gaussian_mixture_params_reshaped[:, :, :, 4] 
        sigma_y = torch.exp(sigma_y_hat) * math.sqrt(temperature)
        rho_xy_hat = Gaussian_mixture_params_reshaped[:, :, :, 5]
        rho_xy = torch.nn.functional.tanh(rho_xy_hat)
        
        covar_matrix_for_all_Gaussians = torch.zeros(size=(seq_len, batch_size, self.num_Gaussians, 2, 2))
        covar_matrix_for_all_Gaussians = covar_matrix_for_all_Gaussians.to(current_device)
        covar_matrix_for_all_Gaussians[:, :, :, 0, 0] = sigma_x**2
        covar_matrix_for_all_Gaussians[:, :, :, 1, 1] = sigma_y**2
        
        covar = rho_xy * (sigma_x) * (sigma_y)
        covar_matrix_for_all_Gaussians[:, :, :, 0, 1] = covar
        covar_matrix_for_all_Gaussians[:, :, :, 1, 0] = covar
        Gaussian_distributions = torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(loc=mu_for_all_Gaussians, covariance_matrix=covar_matrix_for_all_Gaussians)

After this covar_matrix_for_all_Gaussians has shape (117, 100, 20, 2, 2). Where the last two dimensions represent a 2x2 covariance matrix, each for all 20 Gaussian distributions, for 117 time steps, and for 100 sequences in a batch.
But this covar_matrix_for_all_Gaussians tensor failed the PositiveDefinite check (within torch.distributions.constraints)
class _PositiveDefinite(_Symmetric):
    """
    Constrain to positive-definite matrices.
    """

    def check(self, value):
        sym_check = super().check(value)
        if not sym_check.all():
            return sym_check
        return torch.linalg.cholesky_ex(value).info.eq(0)

when I go into the MultivariateNormal class that is being initialized and checked some values in the debugging console, I was very confused.
Below, “self” refers to the MultivariateNormal object being initialized. Thus, self.covariance_matrix is the [117, 100, 20, 2, 2] tensor that we constructed above.
The PositiveDefinite check failed on the entire tensor. But when we find out which specific indices give the failure (in this case the 2x2 matrix at the [114, 29, 1]-indices), and perform the same check on that 2x2 matrix only, then the check succeeds. Clearly, the batch processing somehow leads to this error?
self.covariance_matrix.shape
>> torch.Size([117, 100, 20, 2, 2])
torch.distributions.constraints._PositiveDefinite().check(self.covariance_matrix).all()  # the PositiveDefinite check on the entire tensor failed
>> torch.Size([])_tensor(False, device='cuda:0')
valid_or_not = torch.distributions.constraints._PositiveDefinite().check(self.covariance_matrix) # let’s find out which specific indices give the failure
valid_or_not.shape
>> torch.Size([117, 100, 20])
invalid_indices = torch.nonzero(~valid_or_not)
invalid_indices
>> torch.Size([1, 3])_tensor([[114,  29,   1]], device='cuda:0')
valid_or_not[114, 29, 1]
>> torch.Size([])_tensor(False, device='cuda:0')
torch.distributions.constraints._PositiveDefinite().check(self.covariance_matrix)[114, 29, 1]  # indeed, accessing the result of the check at this specific indices gives “False”
>> torch.Size([])_tensor(False, device='cuda:0')
self.covariance_matrix[114, 29, 1]
>> torch.Size([2, 2])_tensor([[0.0023, 0.0067],
        [0.0067, 0.0194]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SelectBackward0>)
torch.distributions.constraints._PositiveDefinite().check(self.covariance_matrix[114, 29, 1])  # but when the check is performed on that specific 2x2 matrix, then the check succeeds!
>> torch.Size([])_tensor(True, device='cuda:0')
torch.distributions.constraints._PositiveDefinite().check(self.covariance_matrix)[114, 29, 1]  # again, if we perform the check on entire tensor, the access the 114, 29, 1-indexed result, then we get a failure
>> torch.Size([])_tensor(False, device='cuda:0')

Later, when I tried to find the eigenvalues for this specific 2x2 matrix at [114, 29, 1] index, then I get an eigenvalue that is super close to 0. So perhaps numerical rounding leads to some matrix inaccurately concluded to be not PositiveDefinite?
solve_quadratic(1, -sx2-sy2, sx2*sy2*(1-(rosxsy / math.sqrt(sx2 * sy2))**2))
>> (0.02172636674661413, 3.172062317674529e-10)

Any insights are appreciated. Thanks! I don't know a way to add some epsilons to ensure that my constructed 2x2 covariance matrices to ensure that they are positive-definite. The only solution for me now is to modify the MultivariateNormal class's code to change the check from PositiveDefinite to PositiveSemidefinite. What do you think?
Steps taken:
Please see my debugging console outputs above. The PositiveDefinite check failed on the entire tensor. But when we find out which specific indices give the failure (in this case the 2x2 matrix at the [114, 29, 1]-indices), and perform the same check on that 2x2 matrix only, then the check succeeds. Clearly, the batch processing somehow leads to this error?

right after posting, I found a way to resolve this from another implementation of this same model (Sketch RNN). Let me share this great news!
After digging, I realized that the covariance matrix that ended up failing our PositiveDefinite check was the matrix that previously had rho_xy very close to 1. Even though the resulting covariance matrix did not look anything suspicious, but that weird rho_xy value was probably why the matrix came close to failing PositiveDefinite check.
That’s why these statements from the labml library’s implementation of Sketch RNN helped to prevent this failure, specifically by clamping down rho_xy value to prevent it from being close to 1: https://nn.labml.ai/sketch_rnn/index.html
sigma_x = torch.clamp_min(self.sigma_x, 1e-5)       
sigma_y = torch.clamp_min(self.sigma_y, 1e-5)
rho_xy = torch.clamp(self.rho_xy, -1 + 1e-5, 1 - 1e-5)

Thanks a lot, labml people! You saved me from a mental breakdown.
But my concern still remains about how batch processing through PyTorch function like _PositiveDefinite() check would lead to error, even as the same check succeeded on individual matrix?
